# How to open connection to redis from signalr hub

Tags: redis, signalr, stackexchange.redis

I am using a redis server as my backplane for my signalr application.

I fully understand how to write and read from the redis server - but what is the best practice for connecting to the redis server from my hub class?

For example adding a reference to the server as below using stackexchange.redis, but where and when to call this in my hub class? Obviously I want to persist this connection. I'm totally stuck on this right now.

```
Private redis As StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379")
```

Comment: You don't need to use the StackExchange.Redis library to have Redis as a SignalR backplane. See [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis).

Comment: thanks but yes - I am following the way in the link you give. My question relates to how to open a connection to redis from the hub so that I can add and delete keys, maintain lists etc?

Comment: I followed instructions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690521.aspx and then just called it each time from the hub e.g. Dim db As IDatabase = RedisConnection.connection.GetDatabase()